# How to user user input variables in Build file?

Tags: variables, ant, build

prompted for user entry by I'm new to ant and I was wondering if it would be possible to create a global variable in the build file so that I can use it repeatedly throughout the file itself.

For example, if the command were 'ant a', I would be able to use that value 'a' throughout the build file (for example in a file path i.e C:/test/a).

The reason I want to know how to do this is because there are multiple values like 'a' (lets say all the letters in the alphabet), and instead of copying and pasting the same code 26 times, I would be able to have 1 piece of code that takes different values (depending on what the user enters). In java you are able to have a variable storing the user input, and use that variable throughout the code (same idea here).

I tried searching for this but wasn't sure how to word it.

**UPDATE**
With the help of some people I managed to solve what I needed.
So I managed to use Input Task to kind of fix my problem. I prompted the user for an entry by using the following command:

Then I can just use the value entered by the user anywhere i want by simply writing ${hold.it}. For example in a file path "C:/go/to/${hold.it}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Ant `properties`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) and the [`property`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) task used to set them. For example, you can define a property named `prop1` and pass its value using `ant -Dprop1=some_value`.

A property is "global" since after defining it, any part of the buildfile can use it.

Comment: Well I tried "ant -Dprop=abc" and when I tried to echo a message with the file path, for example c:/test/${prop}, i reveice c:/test/null. Null was the inital value set for 'prop' in the build file.

Comment: Could you update the question and specify the buildfile, specifically how you're defining the property?

Comment: Sure i'll update it. I actually did it another way by using the input task avilable in ant. Then I just referenced that value wherever I needed it